# Caffe with matlab support build issues

Tags: caffe, matcaffe

I am having issues building caffe with matlab wrapper.
Using the following build commands

```
cmake  -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER:STRING=gcc-5 -DBUILD_matlab=ON ..

make
```

I get

```
[...]/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.cpp:18:27: fatal error: caffe/caffe.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "caffe/caffe.hpp"
                           ^
compilation terminated.

make[2]: *** [matlab/CMakeFiles/matlab.dir/build.make:61: ../matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64] Error 255
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1173: matlab/CMakeFiles/matlab.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```